# Do I need to create own server zone in BIND?

Tags: bind, dns-zone

Newbie question. In BIND I have to create two Name Servers, ns1 and ns2, to resolve 3 domains related to 3 websites in Apache.
Apache and its 3 domains are on a dedicated server named srv1.domain.tld
The two name servers are on two VPS (ns1.domain.tld and ns2.domain.tld)
Obviously all domains are managed by the provider with its DNS panel. In the 3 domains panel I indicated the two new personal Name Servers while in the domain.tld panel I inserted the three A records for the two VPS and the dedicated server.

I wonder if in BIND, in addition to the 3 zones for the three domains, I have to create a zone for domain.tld because in this case it will replace the zone managed by the provider and its settings. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You need a zone on your self-hosted nameserver for each domain which has NS records pointing to this nameserver.

Comment: This is already done. In my self-hosted nameserver ns1.domain.tld there are three zones for the domains domain-a.tld, domain-b.tld and domain-c.tld.
My question is another: should I also create the zone for domain.tld? This already exists on the provider.

Comment: Does domain.tld NS point to your self-hosted nameserver? If it does - then you need this zone on your server, if it doesn't - then you don't.

Comment: So I have to create the domain.tld zone and create in it all the records that are now present in the provider's DNS panel for this same domain, right?

Comment: if we speak about a public domain, 2 NS are required which has to be 2 physically installed. moreover it is also required to have 2 different IPs. for a local domain only one is required

Comment: You need to have the entire set of all DNS resource records for a zone present on each server pointed by NS records for the domain.

Comment: It’s a little difficult to decipher this post. You might review it to improve clarity. If I’m understanding correctly you aren’t pointing domain.tld to a different name server, those records are still hosted by the original DNS provider. All you did was change the name servers for 3 other domains. So you would not need to create domain.tld in BIND. Am I misunderstanding?